# Python - GUI (TKinter), getting variables from other functions without running the whole function agan

Tags: python, function, variables, tkinter

I do have an problem i can't realy get solved. The problem is, i do have two separate buttons. In one button I want to load a selected file. And with the other one i want to do some searching.
However i can't get de variables from one function to the otherone without running the whole function again. So that means, the find button is useless now.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from Tkinter import *
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename


def openFile():
    Tk().withdraw()
    txtFile = askopenfilename(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=(("something", "*.txt"),("All Files", "*.*") ))
    print(txtFile)
    return txtFile


def Function():
    txtFile = openFile()
    with open(txtFile) as fp, open(('c:/map/test.txt'), 'w') as fo:
        for line in fp:

            if ('Hello') in line:
                content = line.strip() + " Hello detected "
            else:
                content = line.strip()
            fo.write(content + "\n")


def presentGUI():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("simulation")

    # Buttons
    button1 = Button(root, text="Select .txt file", command=openFile)
    button2 = Button(root, text="Run !", width=28, command=Function)

    # grid
    button1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    button2.grid(row=3, columnspan=3)

    root.mainloop()

presentGUI()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two methods

1. Use a global variable for txtFile
2. Use OO and create the functions as part of a class so that they can share variables.

I've given you an example of option 2. Since It is my preferred method of working.

If you click "Run !" and haven't clicked on "Select .txt file" first it will prompt you to select a file anyway.
You can access the self.txtFile variable from any method inside the 'Application' class.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from Tkinter import *
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,**kw):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent,**kw)
        self.txtFile = None
        self.presentGUI()

    def openFile(self):
        ##Tk().withdraw()
        self.txtFile = askopenfilename(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=(("something", "*.txt"),("All Files", "*.*") ))
        print(self.txtFile)

    def Function(self):
        if self.txtFile == None:
            self.openFile()
        with open(self.txtFile) as fp, open(('c:/map/test.txt'), 'w') as fo:
            for line in fp:

                if ('Hello') in line:
                    content = line.strip() + " Hello detected "
                else:
                    content = line.strip()
                fo.write(content + "\n")


    def presentGUI(self):      
        # Buttons
        self.button1 = Button(self, text="Select .txt file", command=self.openFile)
        self.button2 = Button(self, text="Run !", width=28, command=self.Function)

        # grid
        self.button1.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.button2.grid(row=3, columnspan=3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("simulation")
    app = Application(root)
    app.grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works axactly how I want it. Never realy get into classes, going to work on it!